# Getting 403 errors using Data Management API's GetFolder Call

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I get the following error, supplying the same username and password used to generate this token allows me access via the BIM 360 site.

Error calling GetFolder: {"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"00ec6eb7-
697c-47b4-b66e-164f0716fc83","status":"403","detail":"Forbidden"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have your account registered for access to BIM 360 Data from DM API. Please follow the steps in this blog post to obtain the access required.

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-activating-api-access-to-docs/

Comment: So i doubt it is permissions based because from the desktop sample viewer app, I can view the tree just fine, but from the BIM360 issues sample app I can't browse the tree. Is something wrong with the issues sample?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to use the Issues sample live version to read your Bim information? You will need to include the configuration for this app as well in your custom integrations. But for what I see is that the live app is not exposing the client_id value that you need to add. There are two ways to fix it, either I ask my teammate to include the configuration, or you spin up your own version of this site and use your client id in the custom integrations section.

Comment: I pulled the sample version down and was running it locally with the custom integrations. So both apps were local, one app can connect to BIM360  and show a list of files and the other cannot (the issues sample).